Would this screenshot be acceptable - as a Screenshot of the Week submission or on the main site?
Is this Screenshot of the Week submission acceptable? Here’s a link to the answer.
The image submission is below. It’s been spoilered because it’s a bit gross (it’s pixelated art of a fleshy monster with multiple appendages/growths and what appear to be distressed faces).

 

Fabian Röling said in a comment,

That is definitely NSFW in some way. I do not think that this should be pinned to the sidebar.

When I asked if I should remove it, they replied,

Not sure. I guess it is fine, as long as not too many people vote for it. :D

(As it stands, it’s tied with the two other most popular submissions.)
To which Joachim replied,

@FabianRöling Which is not really how that rule works, though :D I suppose it might fall under imagery of victims. But for a website aimed specifically at gaming, that seems a little non-sensical, as it can be expected. But I'm not sure. Let's see what the moderators have to say :)

So what do the moderators (or anyone really) have to say? Would this be case-to-case?

And if it's a standing decision, would this be the decision for questions with similar images on the main site?

@galacticninja I saw your edit. I agree with most of it, but I added the allowed-questions tag because of the last part of the question, where I ask if this would be the decision if questions use similar media in their body. I’ll let you decide what to do(?)

I see. I will add it back.

Looks fine to me—it's fairly typical video game content. It comes across more like stylized abstract art than inappropriate content to me.

Every SOTW post has this guideline: "Stack Exchange’s Code of Conduct still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here". While this is a bit of an umbrella rule, it does allow us (the community at large, (not just the mods) to make determinations on a case-by-case basis. With this specific image I agree: I don't see a problem with it.

Id say this image is definitely weird, but it would be like saying 'The Scream' by Munch is NSFW. Its disturbing, maybe, but artistic. I'd say its fine as long as there is no outright nudity or actual gore.

The mods have spoken!

@Daemons Well, the non-mods, mostly :)
